# Lightning Record Edit Form onsuccess not firing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, lightning-recordeditform

Having issues getting the onSuccess Event to fire on my Lightning:recordEditForm. My submit button is outside of the Lightning:recordEditForm and that works perfectly but i'd like to have the onSuccess fire so i can get some of the entered fields and use them elsewhere

Relevent Component Code

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.boopolicyvalues}">
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{! v.policyrecordID}" 
                      objectApiName="Policies__c"

                      onsuccess="{!c.onSuccess}"
                      aura:id="PVeditForm">
    <lightning:messages />
     <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-p-bottom_large">
        <div class="slds-col">
      <lightning:inputField fieldName="Premium_Amount_RV__c" />
     <lightning:inputField fieldName="Cash_Surrender_Value_RV__c" />
     <lightning:inputField fieldName="Gross_Death_Benefit_RV__c" />
     <lightning:inputField fieldName="Values_as_of_RV__c" />
        </div>
       <div class="slds-col">

       <lightning:inputField fieldName="Cost_Basis__c" />
       <lightning:input  name="NewFileName" label="New File Name (Edit if 
Needed)" value="{!v.FinalFileName}"/>
         </div>
       </div>      
</lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:if>
```

Relevent Controller Code

```
handleNavigate: function(cmp, event, helper) {
//Set the File Fields (ie. CSV or Cost Basis) of the changed fields here

    if(cmp.get('v.selectedValue') == 'Policy Values' || 
cmp.get('v.selectedValue') == 'Illustration') {
         cmp.find('PVeditForm').submit();
        var navigate = cmp.get("v.navigateFlow");
        navigate(event.getParam("action"));
    }
    if(cmp.get('v.selectedValue') == 'Annual Values') {
        cmp.find('AVeditForm').submit();
        var navigate = cmp.get("v.navigateFlow");
        navigate(event.getParam("action"));
    }
    if(cmp.get('v.selectedValue')== 'Cost Basis') {
        cmp.find('CBeditForm').submit();
        var navigate = cmp.get("v.navigateFlow");
        navigate(event.getParam("action"));
    }


},

onSuccess: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    console.log(5);
       var payload = event.getParams().response;
       console.log(payload);

    },
```

Shouldnt it fire if the record is sucessfully updated (which i have confirmed many times that it has been)

I need to have the button outside the record edit form as this is within a flow and i need to have the flow move to the next page as well.

And although probably not the effecient way to do so, was using the console.log(5) to confirm it doesn't fire at all

Comment: i have a workaround with an Aura Id on the input fields but still would like to figure out why onsuccess isnt firing

Comment: can you rename your method from onSuccess to something else, such as !c.successful

Comment: it was actually !c.handleSuccess for a long time (on both the Lighting:REF and in the controller) and still didnt fire

Comment: I don't think you can submit the form from a button outside the form itself. In that case the `onsucess` or any other function will not get called. I verified this with a quick test. How is your form submit implemented?

Comment: @JayantDas You fortunately can submit from a button outside the form itself. I used cmp.find('AURA.ID').submit(); to do so. My main issue is that the onsuccess attribute does not fire when using this method

Comment: Ah, yes, didn’t think it that way.